# What does "for our sins" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

I am struggling to get my head around the following:

> Hi Andrew, For all our articles we use information from national news
>   organisations **(for our sins)**. Have a look here at the Guardian
>   http://gu.com/p/3xzdk, the BBC http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-24104743
>   and the CAS http://www.cas.org.uk/node/3330

It's a reply to a comment I made on [this blog post](http://www.liblabcon.com/blog/2014/12/10/bankers#comments-outer-wrapper).

Comment: I looked at it and I haven't a clue.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Your profile doesn't specify "location", but it *does* imply you're older than the average user here. By my understanding, if you were a 60+ *British* native speaker, you'd recognise the usage. On the basis of little more than "gut feel", I suspect it's very much a ***BrE*** usage that might well have almost no currency in the US. Can you confirm that you're not BrE?

Comment: I think I flew over the British Isles once on my way from the US to Copenhagen.  That's about as close as it gets.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I know we're a gobby lot, but I doubt you'd have picked up much of our vernacular from that one "not-so-close" encounter! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't come across this usage in years (*decades*, maybe). It's a facetiously self-deprecating "wry humour" expression. A typical usage context in the UK many years ago might be...

> *"Hi Tom! I hear you've been promoted in your job at McDonalds"*
>    *"Yeah, that's right. They made me deputy branch manager, **for my sins**"*

As regards *meaning*, there isn't much really. In my example Tom doesn't really think he's guilty of any past moral transgressions - he's just facetiously implying that his "promotion" could be seen as a "punishment" - because *he doesn't really like/approve of his current circumstances*. See [this question on Yahoo Answers](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080115063713AAZLGUP) for more discussion of the usage (which I'd guess is primarily BrE).

In OP's context, to the extent that it means anything at all, I'd say the writer is just admitting that it's not ideal that he and his colleagues have to *use information from national news organisations* (in an ideal world they would have their *own* team of "newshounds").

Comment: What? It's an everyday idiom in the UK. *I have to take the wife shopping, **for my sins***.

Comment: @WS2: I'm pretty sure in *written* contexts this facetious usage would be swamped by the "literal" one - even in the UK where relatively few people would give any credence to religious notions like "original sin". So there's no easy way to establish current prevalence. My guess is it's less common than *you* think it is (your age and location make it likely you use/hear it more often than the *average* UK native speaker). But I'll freely admit it's probably still *more* common than my personal experience would suggest. I doubt I'd still say it myself, but it's hard to even be sure about that.

Comment: I'm not sure it only involves 'original sin'. I'm sure we have all got enough 'unoriginal sin' to cover the idiomatic use.

Comment: @WS2: I did say *notions **like** "original sin"*. You could mix in allusions to the "personal" sins Catholics admit to in confessionals. Or "karmic consequences" if we don't want to restrict ourselves to Christianity for the "literal" sense. Personally, I think some of my best sins were exceptionally creative and original. :)

Comment: No good deed goes unpunished.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger: Indeed. In irreverent colloquial UK parlance, I can easily imagine Tom in my example trotting that out instead of  ***for my sins***. Particularly if he then went on to say something about how he got punched in the face while breaking up a fight between customers back when he was just a lowly McDonalds floor-sweeper. And the branch manager was so impressed by this that he immediately "promoted" Tom (to a position that paid the same as floor-sweeping, but on the downside made it necessary to work more "unsocial hours").

Comment: IMO the implication is that he isn't proud of it: "For all our articles we use information from national news organisations (I hope you don't take my saying that as hoighty, pompous, and boasting, holier-than-thou)."

Comment: @Chris: Yeah - that's why I said *doesn't really like / **approve*** of whatever situation is being referenced. But it's a fairly vacuous expression that doesn't usually convey much except the speaker's lack of enthusiasm. Another similar one is tacking *worse luck* on the end of some statement about your current activity/circumstances - which doesn't in any meaningful sense invite sympathy, or rail against the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune. I think it's mainly just a way of downplaying the importance of whatever you're talking about.

Comment: My sense tallies entirely with @WS2 - quite common in my neck of the (UK) woods. And often enough qualified with "which must be many", if the situation is sufficiently dire (as in, "And as if that wasn't bad enough, I've just been sent on a senior management course for my sins -- which must be many!").

Comment: "Worse luck" wold mean explicitly that the speaker disapproves of and dislikes the situation. "Sins" is neutral about the situation, resigned to it, perhaps even positive about it as being the best available possibility ... but it trying to narrow any gap between the speaker and the audience. "They made me Lord Chief Justice for my sins" means "They made me Lord Chief Justice because I deserved it because I worked at it, but in spite of that I hope that we can still be buddies and you won't hold it against me."

Comment: @ChrisW: I suppose at the end of the day it's a matter of opinion (the speaker's) what he means by it. But to me, if *actual* sins are at all relevant to the facetious usage it's more likely to be implying *"[blah blah] - which I **didn't** deserve"*, rather than being a claim that I *did* deserve whatever circumstances are being described. This kind of "meaning reversal" is common in facetious/sarcastic usages.

Comment: I think it's disclaiming the social sin of pride: "I don't think I'm holier than thou". Your example of "being promoted" is probably something which you did actually deserve. The OP's "using information from national news organisations" is presumably something which they're doing on purpose for some sufficiently good reason. But saying that can make the speaker sound distant (e.g. "we use national news organisations, you low-life, we're important and you're not").

Answer (score 3):

I've always supposed this phrase derives from  *Acts of Contrition*, as recited by penitent sinners after confession.  See, for example, the several forms given near the end of  [rc.net's *Confession*](http://www.rc.net/crookston/holytrinity/confession.html) page, somewhat as follows:

> Oh, my God, I am heartily sorry for my sins.  Because I dread the loss of heaven and the pains of hell, but most of all because they offend Thee [...]  I firmly resolve, with the help of Thy grace to confess my sins, to do penance and to avoid the near occasions of sin.

That is, *for my sins* may be used to suggest (sometimes humorously) that what someone is doing or going to do is a sort of penance.

In the example quoted in the question, it's possible the phrase is being misused, if the speaker does *not* mean to imply that what they are doing is a penance, but rather a sin in itself.

However, if they have in the past used shady sources, it may be saying they are now required to used the national news sources mentioned.